# Как объединить все используемые стили в один файл HTML

Tags: html, css

Есть страница на сайте, которая использует стили хранящиеся на сайте в папке css. Мне нужно сделать независимую html страничку, со всеми необходимыми стилями внутри документа между тэгами `<style></style>`.
Вопрос: Как можно сделать такую страничку, которая будет включать только используемые на ней стили?

Comment: Учите Gulp, SASS или тому подобные инструменты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE  html>
  <html lang="ru">
    <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">                 
      <title>Mold</title>
</head>
<body>
<header><h1>HEADER</h1></header>
<main >
<section >
 <h2>section</h2>
 <div >
 Попробуйте через,<br>
 сброс стилей при помощи JS,<br>
 для переопределения приоритета,<br>
 что бы исключить библиотеки.<br>
 Стили присваивать придётся,<br> 
 через JS как на этой странице.<br>
 Правда заморочено получается.
 </div>
</section>
</main>
<footer ><h4>FOOTER</h4></footer>
<script >
/*RESET(сброс стилей при помощи JS)*/
/*здесь вставте теги те что будете использовать на странице*/
var _reset = document.querySelectorAll("dody,header,main,section,article,aside,footer,h1,h2,h4");
for(var i = 0; i < _reset.length; i++)
{console.log(_reset[i]);
_reset[i].style.cssText = "margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0;font-size:1rem;font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;vertical-align:baseline;line-height:1;color:hsla(0,0%,0%,1);background:transparent;";
};
/*Ваши css стили*/
/*BODY*/
document.querySelector("body").style.cssText = "width:100%;margin:0 auto;background:hsla(40,80%,60%,.8);text-shadow:0px 0px 1px hsla(0,0%,0%,.6);";
/*HEADER*/
document.querySelector("header").style.cssText = "border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;height:2em;margin:0 auto;margin-top:2%;padding:.5%;background:hsla(240,80%,60%,.8);";
/*HEADER H1*/
document.querySelector("header h1").style.cssText = "border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;margin:0 auto;background:hsla(0,0%,100%,1);font:700 100%/1.8 sans-serif;color:hsla(0,80%,40%,1);text-align:center;";
/*MAIN*/
document.querySelector("main").style.cssText = "display:block;border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;margin:.5% auto;padding:.5%;background:hsla(0,0%,80%,.8);";
/*SECTION*/
document.querySelector("main section").style.cssText = "display:block;border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;margin:0 auto;padding:.5%;background:hsla(0,80%,40%,.8);";
/*SECTION H2*/
document.querySelector("section h2").style.cssText = "border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;margin:0 auto;background:hsla(0,0%,80%,1);font:700 100%/1.8 sans-serif;color:hsla(240,80%,40%,1);text-align:center;";
/*SECTION DIV*/
document.querySelector("section div").style.cssText = "width:90%;margin:0 auto;background:hsla(0,0%,100%,1);font:700 100%/1.8 sans-serif;color:hsla(0,0%,0%,1);text-align:center;";
/*FOOTER*/
document.querySelector("footer").style.cssText = "border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;height:2em;margin:0 auto;padding:.5%;background:hsla(70,80%,60%,.8);";
/*FOOTER H4*/
document.querySelector("footer h4").style.cssText = "border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);width:90%;margin:0 auto;background:hsla(0,0%,100%,1);font:700 100%/1.8 sans-serif;color:hsla(0,80%,40%,1);text-align:center;";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```